# How do I recover from a failed import in Nim?

Tags: include, wrapper, nim-lang, include-guards

In [Nim](http://nim-lang.org) I can write the following code to import an external module:

```
import myFancyPantsModule
...
# And here I'd use the fancyPants proc
```

This works fine as long as I have the module, but for people who might download the code and not have the module installed compilation will fail with a not very user friendly message:

```
$ nim c fancyProgram.nim
fancyProgram.nim(1, 7) Error: cannot open 'myFancyPantsModule'
```

Is there any way I can wrap around the `import` so that I can *catch* it similar to an exception and execute an alternative branch of code similar to the `when` statement? I was hoping to find some `importable`-like macro or something which I could use like:

```
when importable(myFancyPantsModule):
    # And here I'd use the fancyPants proc
else:
    quit("Oh, sorry, go to https://github.com/nim-lang/nimble and install " &
      " the myFancyPantsModule using the nimble package manager")
```

In fact, rather than a simple error message I would like to make some modules optional, so that compilation still proceeds ahead, maybe with reduced functionality. Is this possible?

**SOLUTION EDIT**: Based on the answer here is my version how to solve the issue, first you need a `moduleChecker` binary with the following source:

```
import os, osproc

let tmpFile = getTempDir() / "dynamicModuleChecker.nim"

proc checkModule(module: string) =
  except:
    echo "Cannot write ", tmpFile, " to check the availability of modules"
    quit(1)
  writeFile(tmpFile, "import " & module & "\n")

  finally: removeFile(tmpFile)

  except:
    echo("Cannot run \"nimrod check\" to check the availability of modules")
    quit(1)
  if execCmdEx("nim check " & tmpFile).exitCode != 0:
    echo("Cannot import module " & module & ".")
    quit(1)
  else:
    echo "OK"

if ParamCount() < 1:
  quit("Pass as first parameter the module to check")
else:
  checkModule(ParamStr(1))
```

Then, having this command available the following macro can be used:

```
import macros

macro safeImport(module, message: string): stmt =
  if "OK" == gorge("./moduleChecker " & module.strVal):
    result = newNimNode(nnkStmtList).add(
      newNimNode(nnkImportStmt).add(
      newIdentNode(module.strVal)))
  else:
    error("\nModule " & module.strVal &
      " not available.\n" & message.strVal)

safeImport("genieos",
  "Please install \"http://gradha.github.io/genieos/\"")
```

It is too unfortunate that a separate process has to be spawned, not only for the external compilation but also another one to generate the temporary file to check, as there is no `staticWrite` in the current version to generate files at compile time.

Comment: A better mechanism was requested to the Nimrod authors, see https://github.com/Araq/Nimrod/issues/671.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no (easy) way to do this. What you can do is to use a separate configuration/check stage in your build. E.g.:

```
import macros, os, osproc

proc checkModule(module, howtomessage: string) =
  except:
    echo("Cannot write .conftest.nim to check the availability of modules")
    quit(1)
  writeFile(".conftest.nim", "import " & module & "\n")

  except: nil
  removeFile(".conftest.nim")

  except:
    echo("Cannot run \"nimrod check\" to check the availability of modules")
    quit(1)
  if execCmdEx("nimrod check .conftest.nim").exitCode != 0:
    echo("Cannot import module " & module & ".")
    echo(howtomessage)
    quit(1)

checkModule "foobar", "Please install it using the Babel package manager"
```

Then run something like:

```
nimrod cc --run configure.nim && nimrod cc main.nim
```

That's assuming the code above is stored in a file called `configure.nim` and the nimrod executable is in your path (otherwise, you'll have to specify the nimrod path in `configure.nim` also).